# How to notify offline Firebase Cloud Messaging web-clients that they have unread messages

Tags: reactjs, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am using Firebase Cloud Messaging [FCM](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging?authuser=0) in a web app, my scenario is as follows:

User-A tries to send user-B (who is offline) a message.

When this happens I would like to email user-B so that they know to come back to the web-app to get their message.

So, the two pieces of information on which the decision to contact a user are:

1. that they are offline
2. they have an unread message(s)

I have looked at potentially polling things like [firebase.database.OnDisconnect](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.database.OnDisconnect) or perhaps polling auth.

As this is server-less there are no hooks, so what should I use for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> As this is server-less there are no hooks

Actually, Firebase has a built in system to listen for database changes (such as the `onDisconnect` write firing) in [Cloud Functions for Firebase](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/database-events). For example say that you use a [presence system as shown in the docs](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/web/offline-capabilities#section-sample), storing the connection(s) for each user under `/onlineUsers/$uid`. That means that as long as the user is online on any device, their `/onlineUsers/$uid` will exist, and when their last connection is closed (or at least when the server detects that) their `/onlineUsers/$uid` will disappear.

Now you can set up a Cloud Function that runs in response to a `/onlineUsers/$uid` being deleted with something like:

```
exports.userWentOffline = functions.database.ref('/onlineUsers/{uid}')
    .onDelete((snapshot, context) => {
      console.log('userWentOffline', context.params.uid);
      return null;
    });
```

You can do whatever you want in the body of this Cloud Function.

---

If you want to take action on another trigger if the user is no longer connected, you'll want to check whether their `/onlineUsers/$uid` node exists.

---

A few things to keep in mind:

- A single user/UID can have multiple connections to the database, even when they're on a single device. So be sure to implement the presence system as shown at the end of the docs I linked, which allows for this.
- If the connection between the client and the server is not cleanly terminated, it may take up to a few minutes before the server detects that the client is gone, and fires the `onDisconnect` handlers. So when the Cloud Function runs, you'll want to detect which recent messages have not been delivered.